# Understanding how javascript hashtables work

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain to me why the code sample below reports true? I would have assumed that like in C# the instance of Test1 != instance of Test2.

**Update:** So I think I will go with some unique identifier stored in the base of both Test1 and Test2.

```
function Test1() { };

function Test2() { };

var test1 = new Test1();

var test2 = new Test2();

var dict = new Array();

dict[test1] = true;

alert(dict[test2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I've upvoted all of you.

Comment: *related* [Hash/associative array using several objects as key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983436/hash-associative-array-using-several-objects-as-key/6983486) I provided an answer which shows how this could be done (not saying that this is the only or best way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys in 'hashtables' (objects, basically) are always strings. So anything you add will be converted to a string.

```
new Test1();
```

returns a instance of `Test1`. Converted as a string, this is:

```
"[object Object]"
```

The same goes for `Test2`. So in fact, when storing `true` under the key of `new Test1()` as a string, you are working with the exact same record as the one by obtaining with the key `new Test2()` as a string. In other words,

```
(new Test1()).toString() == (new Test2()).toString();
```

The actual object is therefore simply:

```
{
 "[object Object]": true
}
```

A solution is overwriting `.toString()` like this:

```
Test1.prototype.toString = function() { return "Test1" };
Test2.prototype.toString = function() { return "Test2" };
```

Then `dict[test1]` will be stored as `dict['Test1']` and `dict[test2]` as `dict['Test2']`, which allows you to differ between them. Still, manually setting `dict['Test1']` would overwrite things. As far as I know, there is no way to assign an object as a key.

Comment: Allright, so in the only chance to solve this would be to have both Test1 and Test2 implement some unique identifier property.

Comment: @Oliver Weichold: You could also overwrite `toString`. Let me edit.

Answer (score 5):

Your object (JavaScript's hashtable) is **not** using the instance of `test1` or `test2`, but the string representation, as a key. Since both `test1` and `test2` have the same string representation: `"[object Object]"`, the `true` value is associated with that key.

Try doing something like below instead:

```
function Test1(id) { this.id=id };

function Test2(id) { this.id=id };

var test1 = new Test1('1'); 
var test2 = new Test2('2'); 
var dict = {};

dict[test1.id] = true;

console.log(dict[test1.id]);
```

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to change to get it to work the way I want it.

Comment: maybe do something like: function Test1(id) { this.id=id };

function Test2(id) { this.id=id };

var test1 = new Test1('1'); 
var test2 = new Test2('2'); 
var dict = new Array();

dict[test1.id] = true;

console.log(dict[test1.id]);

Comment: @Oliver You can make toString return whatever you want if you set up your objects right.  Also, you should stop thinking about Javascript in terms of C# - they are not alike except in syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript objects aren't exactly hashtables; they're actually objects with **string** keys.

When you use an object as a key, the object is converted to a string by calling `toString()`.
`toString()` will return the same string for all custom classes (unless you create your own `toString`), so they end up using the same key.

Answer (score 2):

**First:** Use arrays only for numerical keys. For anything else use objects.

Property names can only be strings. Anything else is converted to its string representation. In case of objects, this is `[object Object]` or whatever `toString()` returns.

Which means, that if you want to make both objects distinguishable, you have to override this method and let it return something which is unique to each instance.

This question might help you: [Hash/associative array using several objects as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983436/hash-associative-array-using-several-objects-as-key/6983486)