# How to put and get the value by the key using object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to use the functionality of dictionary in JavaScript?

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222/how-to-use-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-javascript) the specified way is working, but I am setting the function instance as a key like this:

```
Scale = function ()
{
    this.Collections = {};
    this.IndexTracker = {};
    this.UpdateIndex = function ()
    {
        var index = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < this.Collections.length; i++ )
        {
            this.SetIndex( this.Collections[i], index++ );
        }
    }
    this.SetIndex = function ( obj, value )
    {
        this.IndexTracker[obj] = value;
    }
    this.GetIndex = function ( obj, value )
    {
        return this.IndexTracker[obj];
    }
}
```

`this.Collections` will hold the some function instance.

The problem here is the function instance is overwritten by the next function instance in `this.Collections`. The the length of the `Collections` always is `1`. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: It might be a scoping issue - use the `var` keyword so the variables (`this.Collections`,etc) only exist within the scope of the function (object), rather than being saved into the global scope.

Comment: Keys will be treated as strings. If you a different data type as key, it will be converted to a string. The default string representation is `[object Object]` so you have think about something else to use as key (e.g. use your own object serialization).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hash/associative array using several objects as key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983436/hash-associative-array-using-several-objects-as-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example:

```
var Scale = function () {
    var _Collections = {},
    _IndexTracker = {},
    ret = function () {
        function UpdateIndex() {
            var index = 0,i,l;
            for (i = 0,l=_Collections.length; i < l; i++) {
                this.SetIndex(_Collections[i], index++);
            }
        }
        function SetIndex(obj, value) {
            _IndexTracker[obj] = value;
        }
        function GetIndex(obj, value) {
            return _IndexTracker[obj];
        }
        return {
            UpdateIndex : UpdateIndex,
            SetIndex : SetIndex,
            GetIndex : GetIndex
        };
    };
    return ret;
}();
```